# UISplitviewController(window.rootViewController) viewcontrollers not deallocated on iOS8 after exchanging it with UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, dealloc, uiwindow

So I have this problem.

I have a simple test project in which i have an `UINavigationController` as my `window.rootViewController`.
In the `navigationBar` I have a button which executes following code:

```
MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];

DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.window
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^(void) {
                    BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
                    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Pressing this button will as the code shows, simply replace the existing `rootViewController` with an `UISplitViewController`.
After pressing the button everything is fine. The `UISplitViewController` is my rootViewController.
After pressing a specific Button in the `UISpliViewController` following code will be executed:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^(void) {
                    BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
                    self.window.rootViewController = self.navCTL;
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    self.splitViewController = nil;
                }];
```

This code simply does the reverse of which was done with the above button.
When pressed the `rootViewController` will be replaced.

Now here's the awkward thing.
On iOS7 and less the `viewControllers` of the `UISplitViewController` will be deallocated, after pressing the second button.
That's how i want it and how i would expect it.
On iOS8 it's different. After pressing the second button they won't be deallocated, until i once again press the first button and the `rootViewController` will be a `UISplitViewController` (a new one) again.

Comment: I've had this problem too. I believe it to be a bug in the framework. I made a radar for it - no idea if it'll be looked at.